# What is the "G" dashboard light on Renault Clio?

Tags: renault, warning-light, clio

Does anyone know what the G symbol is on the dashboard of a Renault  Clio? I cannot find any information on it in the car manual or online.

It is a Clio dci 1.5 2007 - it came on when the car was started around 2 weeks ago.

[image]

Comment: What year is your Clio?

Comment: What does the owners manual say?

Comment: To be honest, I dont see it in here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.renaultusa.com/News/DriversManuals/Clio.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi7x-P8q_bkAhVJOKwKHaAWD9kQFjAKegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3bHE-BLbYLu2kuzDLr4GuY&cshid=1569771371882 Unless it's not marked as a symbol

Comment: When did the G appear, was it when the esp warning signal came on ? Or was a button pressed

Comment: It is a Clio dci 1.5 2007 - it came on when the car was started around 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR
**Gallons** of fuel consumed since last reset.

---

Checking a picture of that display online where unlit LCD characters could be seen, I was able to assemble the following line of letters:

```
MPHKM/HL/100MPG
```

Now checking the Owners's Manual (as provided by @hello moto 's comment), on pages 1.66 onward, the modes of operation listed have the following units:

```
KM/H, KM, L, L/100
```

A parallel to imperial units (unconfirmed) on the LCD letters would be:

```
MPH, M, G, MPG
```

So my best guess is that your car is in imperial units and you've spent 105.2 **gallons** of fuel since last reset, corresponding to mode (page 1.66):

> **b) Journey parameters**
>    Fuel consumed since the last reset

Try cycling through the different modes as described on the manual and see if that logic matches.

Comment: Sounds like a good answer to me. That car needs an oil change as well...