# Renault Clio 2006 dashboard symbol is a car with a g sign

Tags: renault, dashboard, clio

Renault 2006 dashboard symbol car with a g what does it mean and how do we get rid of it

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there any way you could edit your question and insert an image of the symbol you're talking about? This would allow us all to be on the same page and give you better information.

Comment: Well here are some: https://www.drivingtesttips.biz/renault-clio-dashboard-engine-warning-lights-symbols.html

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/71663/what-is-the-g-dashboard-light-on-renault-clio